# Trazar elipsoide con Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

Estoy intentando graficar un elipsoide en 3D utilizando Python, pero estoy teniendo dificultades para graficarlo correctamente. He intentado utilizar diferentes bibliotecas como matplotlib y numpy, pero no estoy seguro de cómo implementar la ecuación del elipsoide de manera adecuada

La formula que me pasaron es:

```
(x**2/a**2)+(y**2/b**2)+(z**2/c**2) = 1
```

Gracias de antemano

Este es mi codigo (despejé z):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def f(x, y):
    return (np.sqrt(1 - ((x**2)/2) - ((y**2)/2)))


x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
y = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)


X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

Z = f(X, Y)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, alpha=0.3, color='green')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, -Z, alpha=0.3, color='green')
plt.show()
```

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

El problema principal en tu código es que la función f(x, y) que has definido no está calculando correctamente los valores de Z para formar el elipsoide. La ecuación del elipsoide que estás utilizando es correcta, pero al despejar z de esa ecuación, se hace necesario considerar las constantes a, b y c, que representan los semiejes del elipsoide.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Definir los parámetros del elipsoide
a = 5
b = 3
c = 2

# Generar puntos en la superficie del elipsoide
x = np.linspace(-a, a, 100)
y = np.linspace(-b, b, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# Calcular la coordenada Z para cada punto
Z = np.sqrt(1 - ((X**2) / a**2) - ((Y**2) / b**2))

# Graficar la superficie del elipsoide
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, alpha=0.3, color='green')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, -Z, alpha=0.3, color='green')

# Mostrar la gráfica
plt.show()
```

Asegúrate de ajustar los valores de a, b y c según las dimensiones deseadas del elipsoide.

Comment: Hola gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisar [answer] y también [CHATGPT está prohibido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido), saludos.